# Rails collection based on prior selection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using Activeadmin and have a form where a user selects which `notebook` they'd like to add a `note` to.

```
f.input :notebook
f.input :note, as: :select, collection: Note.all
```

However, I'd like to be able to dynamically change that collection based on what the user has selected as the Notebook. If a notebook has a `notebook_type` of `evernote`, I don't want to allow the user to choose some of the notes that are included in `Note.all`. (I've gotten that scope down with the help of a very kind StackOverflow user).

For reference, here's that method:

```
class Notebook < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes

  def self.notes_without_check_lists
    all.reject { |notebook| notebook.notes.any? { |note| note.note_type == 'check_list' } }
  end
end
```

I'm already using some jQuery to handle another section of the form and using an on change event like this:

```
$("#note_notebook_id").on 'change', (e) ->
```

But essentially, I'd like to somehow **toggle the `collection:` between `Note.all` and `Note.notes_without_check_lists` depending on which Notebook the user has chosen.**

Much thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the best solution is create a new [member_action](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#member-actions) that receive a notebook ID and return a JSON of all availables notes for it.

Example:

```
member_action :notes, method: :get do
  notebook = Notebook.find params[:notebook_id]
  render :json, notebook.notes_without_check_lists
end
```

Now, use jQuery to make the request when notebook id change, clear all options of the old select box and add the new options.

Example:

```
$("#note_notebook_id").on('change', function() {
    var nb_id = $(this).val();
    $.get('http://yourdomain/admin/notebook/notes?notebook_id=' + nb_id, function(result) {
        $('#note').empty();
        $.each(result.data, function(item) {
           $('#note').append('<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.name+'</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

This is an idea... use it as base for your solution.